# SQL Server Group By

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains a reference and a name. There are some issues with the data whereby there are more than 2 distinct names for a reference which isn't allowed.

Is there a quick query I can write to find all references that have more than 1 associated name?

Sorry, just to clarify:

I can have many names, and many references but only one name associated with each reference. If there are 2 different names associated with a single reference, I need to show these.

Comment: Once you fix your data, make sure you apply suitable constraints to prevent this broken data from being inserted again in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can group it by referenceand then select all the entries that have more than one:

```
select reference, count(*) 
from myTable
group by reference
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT reference, COUNT(name)
FROM @table
GROUP BY reference
HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
```

Sample data:

```
declare @table table(reference varchar(5), name int)
INSERT INTO @table values('Ref#1', 1)
INSERT INTO @table values('Ref#1', 2)
INSERT INTO @table values('Ref#2', 3)
INSERT INTO @table values('Ref#2', 3)
INSERT INTO @table values('Ref#3', 4)
```

Output:

```
| Ref#1 | 2 |
| Ref#2 | 2 |
```

Comment: That would work, but the same name and reference can appear more than once. However, only one distinct name and reference can appear.

Comment: You mean that this is not possible when you have two rows with the same reference and name in the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I managed it like this:

```
SELECT ref, COUNT(name)
FROM table
GROUP BY ref
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(name)) > 1
```

Comment: If you use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1`, then also use `SELECT ref, COUNT(DISTINCT name)`

Comment: And `DISTINCT` is not a function, parenthesis are not needed around `name`

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the minimal name and maximal name for a particular reference are different, then there must be at least two names associated with that reference:

```
SELECT Reference, MIN(Name), MAX(Name)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Reference
HAVING MIN(Name) < MAX(Name)
```